# Convert from byte array to string and string to byte array in java

Tags: java, string, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion of byte[] into a String and then back to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758654/conversion-of-byte-into-a-string-and-then-back-to-a-byte)

I have the following piece of code, I'm trying to get the test to pass, but can't seem to get my head around the various forms of encoding that go on in the java world.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {

static final byte[] A = { (byte)0x11, (byte)0x22, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x77, (byte)0x88, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xAA };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = new String(A);

    byte[] b = s.getBytes();

    if (Arrays.equals(A,b)) { 
       System.out.println("TEST PASSED!"); 
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("TEST FAILED!");
    }

}
}
```

I guess my question is: What is the correct way to convert a byte array of arbitary bytes to a Java String, then later on convert that same Java String to another byte array, which will have the same length and same contents as the original byte array?

Comment: I get test passed, are you sure you're running your latest code?

Comment: What's the encoding of your original byte array?

Comment: @Mike K:  http://ideone.com/To8IK

Comment: @MarkElliot: This is some binary data, there is no underlying 'encoding' for A.

Comment: @Xander Tulip If there is a string, there is always encoding. If you print out the bytes individually `for(byte iB : b)  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(iB ));`, you'll see the trouble starts at 0x88.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a specific encoding:

```
String s = new String(A, "ISO-8859-1");

byte[] b = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/1ZOsl)

Comment: that looks like it did the trick. I was one follow up question, is it correct to use a java String to pass a byte array across JNI boundaries?

Comment: @XanderTulip I'm not really familiar with JNI but there generally using string to represent byte array could be lossy. Isn't there a jbyteArray type for this?

Comment: @XanderTulip You can pass byte arrays across JNI boundaries.See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html#array

Answer (score 4):

Use Base64.

Apache Commons Codec has a [Base64 class](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) which supports the following interface:

```
String str = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
byte[] newBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(str);
```

Comment: This seems like a very round about way to get a very specific and simple string conversion done, futhermore it requires the use of a nonstandard java library, not sure if the OP had that in mind. Is this a joke answer? ;)

Comment: Yes, it is round-about. No, it is not a joke answer =) 

The OP indicated that the bytes are arbitrary.

If the encoding (magic!) he chooses isn't supported by the platform or the byte array contains values that aren't supported by the encoding, an exception will be raised.

Even assuming he selects the right encoding, has a regression testing suite and never intends to move platforms, he is probably using Apache Commons for something else - it's a very common library.

ps. apologies for the late response